# zip/compress a .bin file

Tags: zip, compression, binary

I have a .bin file size of 8MB; is it possible to compress it or zip it?

Tried with 7z but 8MB -> 7.90 MB so any relevant changes.

Is there any other tools? Or simply is it not possible?

Comment: Chances are it won't compress much. You can give this a try: `bzip2 --best file.bin`

Comment: There's a [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Data_compression).

Comment: The filename suffix doesn't really say much about how much a file can be compressed. It all comes down to how random the data in the file is. It ought to be fairly easy to test a few common compressors to get a feel for how compressible the file's data is. Already compressed data is rarely compressible by much.

Answer (score 1):

Compression algorithms generally seek out repetition and replace it by short-codes. There is more chance of that with bigger files, and with plain text (often compresses by 80%), and especially HTML and XML (up to 95%). Some formats (audio, photo, video) build compression  into their standards and can actually grow when externally compressed. Binary is pretty much on the borderline.

Answer (score -5):

Chances are, the file is already compressed, in which case you should extract it first and then try using 7-Zip again.

Comment: Can you make this relevant to the question please? It's unclear whether the question is about compressing an _executable_.  Even if it was, it's not clear that the user is using Debian (or any variant of Linux), or what the commands that you present are doing. As far as I can see, you are essentially suggesting that the user should use LZMA compression, right?

Comment: I believe it's exactly what the OP was looking for. The `.bin` extension indicates that it's a binary executable even thou the question is a little vague. The example shows a potential way my answer can be achieved. And no, I've not suggested using a general purpose archive format.

Comment: Should I remove the example? (since the environment is not known and so it's not a direct suggestion)

Comment: A suggestion would be to change the answer to say that _if_ the file is an executable, then they may want to use `upx` in the way that you show.  The way the answer is written now, the essential `upx` command is buried under a lot of extra things that I don't believe is needed even if this was on Debian.  That way you make the answer about `upx`, you have a chance to describe what it does, and how to use it.

Comment: I've changed my answer